# Power system optimization、Arguments are complex

Tags: pyomo, complex-numbers, simpowersystems

In the frequency optimization problem of the power system, a complex number with a parameter value of Z=0.885+j0.310 is encountered. How to define this complex number in Pyomo.Can we use the analogy of solving the node admittance matrix in the power system
Please help me take a look, everyone. Thank you very much!

Comment: this is way too vague and lacks context for any reasonable help.  Suggest you edit your question or post a new one with a specific code issue.